# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' in my code where the values are already integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, traceback

Below is my code. I am new to coding, so I need your help.
I don't know why I am getting this error, because when i tried for the `type()` of all it is showing `class int`.

## My code

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of list:"))
lst = input("Enter the numbers with a space:")
numbers = lst.split()
if len(numbers) == n:
    maxn = -2147483647
    minn = 2147483647
    for number in numbers:
        y = int(number)
        if y > maxn:
            maxn = number
        if y < minn:
            minn = number
    print(maxn, minn)
else:
    print("Numbers greater or less than length")
```

## But I am getting this error on `max` and `min`

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "test.py", line 9, in 
>     if y > maxn:
>   TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You are assigning `maxn` or `minn` the value from `number` (one of the strings from your split list), rather than `y` (that value converted to an integer).

Comment: Isnt it `min`? Not `minn`.

Comment: @jasonharper oh i get it that too is a mistake i guess.. but the error is coming just before this line.. in the if condition..

Comment: Clearly they _aren't_ already integers. And indeed, `lst.split()` doesn't return integers. You're storing an integer in `y`, but you aren't transforming `number` into an integer, so when you run `maxn = number`, you're storing a *string* in `maxn`. Make it `maxn = y`, and _then_ you'll be storing an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of list:"))
lst = input("Enter the numbers with a space:")
numbers = lst.split()
y=0
if len(numbers) == n:
    maxn = -2147483647
    minn = 2147483647
    for number in numbers:
        y = int(number)
        if y > maxn:
            maxn = int(number)#changed here
        if y < minn:
            minn = int(number)#changed here
    print(maxn, minn)
else:
    print("Numbers greater or less than length")
```

a shorter version of your could be,

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of list:"))
lst = input("Enter the numbers with a space:")
numbers = lst.split()
numbers = [ int(x) for x in numbers ]
print(max(numbers),min(numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

Inputs in python are always treated as strings, so need to be converted. Line 3 will do that for you. Also, did you know python can handle any size of number? You can go big!

```
n = int(input("Enter the length of list:"))
lst = input("Enter the numbers with a space:")
numbers = lst.split()
if len(numbers) == n:
    maxn = -2147483647
    minn = 2147483647
    for number in numbers:
        y = int(number)
        if y > maxn:
            maxn = y
        if y < minn:
            minn = y
    print(maxn, minn)
else:
    print("Numbers greater or less than length")
```

Comment: ya i know but i converted the element of numbers in the loop where i needed as in y. But the problem is arising in the variable maxn and minn

Comment: You're right. Updated. Leaving it with the [int(x) for x in lst.split()] means you don't need a y variable later on though, but if you like it that way, you do you.